# base Url in ajax to call controller action in Yii passing parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

my js external script contains the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('[id^="comment"]').click(function(e) {

            $(this).prop('disabled', true);

            if ($(this).val() == 'Save') {
                var $thisClicked = $(this);
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url:"/comment/create/",   

                    success: function(data) {
                        $thisClicked.after(data);
                        $(".form").slideDown(200);
                    }                          
                });
            } else {
                var $thisClicked = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:"/comment/delete/",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $thisClicked.prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
```

my question is what variable should I use to point to the right directory in Yii and how to pass , variables.

I trying to do the equivalent of

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create', array('post_id' => $data['id'], 'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->id)); ?>",
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try what you have above?

Comment: No I'm gettin url error. Because the url is 
localhost/mysite/comment/create instead of  localhost/mysite/index.php/comment/create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this by "hiding" the url in a `data` attribute:

```
<div id="comment" data-url="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create', array('post_id' => $data['id'], 'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->id)); ?>"></div>
```

In your javascript code you can access it by:

```
$("#comment").data('url');
```